# I want to plot data for multiple files with an organized name format using for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, plot

This is the code I used to read multiple files, the data variables are data1, data2, ... , data5

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(10,15,1):
    locals()["data" + str(i-9)] = np.genfromtxt(f'Filename000{i}.dat', delimiter='', skip_header = 1)
```

Now I want to read the columns and rows of the data, using a for loop to run through all variables.
I usually use

```
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

plt.plot(x, y, '-b', label= 'data')
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=15)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How do I for loop it so it reads and plots all these 5 of these data points.

Comment: Can't you replace `locals()["data" + str(i-9)]` with `data` and add your second code sample to the loop?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych The issue is with the second part, the x and y data for the first and second row. I wanna loop it so it goes through data1[:,0], data2[:,0], data3[:,0] and so on. Same with the second column.